# How to programmatically create a bookmark for another connections user?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

We want to create bookmarks programmatically and this works fine if the email parameter matches the account of the currently authenticated user.

The question is, how can we create a bookmark for another user ?
Below is the pseudo we use from the SBT.

```
String apiPath = "/dogear/api/app";
Response<String> postResponse = restClient.doPost(apiPath).parameter("email","another users email").body(body, "application/atom+xml").asString();
```

The log files are not very helpful, in the client we get an ERROR 400 Bad Request

Comment: From what I recall, Bookmarks does not support creating bookmarks on behalf of other users.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBastide so the option would be to get oauth tokens and perform it that way ?
I think this is going to be a challenge since we are setting everything up as a result of migration and no actual user is using the system yet.